# using actionscripts on iphone

Tags: html

I have an html file that uses an xml.Basically, this html has some flash content.What all I have with me is a html file,.xml file, .swf fle & .js file.How can I use this html file on ipad.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The iPhone does not support Flash. You can view the html/xml/js just fine, but the Flash will not display.

Comment: any alternative without using flash.

Comment: Many of the things that Flash does can be achieved using Javascript + html5. It just depends on what you want to do. Video is easy with html5, a complex game made in Flash is hard to port to html5/javascript.

Comment: any link or suggestion to use the similar thing you suggested

Comment: What I suggested? Video in HTML5 should be found within 10 seconds of Googling. All the other stuff can be done learning javascript.